# File name in spark scala showing wrong result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

i am using below code to get the name of the file in Apache Spark but when i am appending it in a `RDD[string]` i am getting different value.

**Below is my code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val text: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/File8.HL7").coalesce(1)

var obrInd = 0

val filenme: RDD[String] = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/cloudera/File8.HL7").map { case (filename, content) => filename}

var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1).mkString("|"))

nameoffile.collect().foreach(println) 

val result: RDD[String] = text.mapPartitions{part =>
        part.map{r => 
        if(code == "OBR")
        r + "|OBR_"+ nameoffile
    }
}
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Below is my output

```
OBR|1||OBR_MapPartitionsRDD[110] at
OBX|1||OBR_MapPartitionsRDD[110] at
OBX|2||OBR_MapPartitionsRDD[110] at    
OBX|3||OBR_MapPartitionsRDD[110] at
OBX|4||OBR_MapPartitionsRDD[110] at
```

**Expected Output:**

```
OBR|1||OBR_File8.HL7
OBX|1||OBR_File8.HL7
OBX|2||OBR_File8.HL7   
OBX|3||OBR_File8.HL7
OBX|4||OBR_File8.HL7
```

but the output of

```
scala> nameoffile.collect().foreach(println)
```

is

```
File8.HL7
```

I don't know what i am missing.

Comment: I don't understand `_.split("/").takeRight(1).mkString("|")`. `takeRight(1)` always returns a collection with a single element so why use `mkString`? If your intention is to take the final element and make a string out of it I would do `_.split("/").last.toString`

Comment: @evan058 I tried your way `_.split("/").last.toString` but still getting same result.

Comment: It was a general suggestion, it shouldn't change the result

Comment: Also it is unclear what exactly the problem is here. What is the expected output? Try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `nameoffile` is an `RDD[String]` but you are trying to concatenate it as if it was a string. You need to use a RDD.join

Comment: it's what @puhlen says. Or you can var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1).collect()

Comment: @evan058 i have updated my question please check.

Comment: @PascalSoucy i tried using `var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1).collect()` but still i am not getting what i want. I have updated my question please check

Comment: @animal I assume that in your real code, you'd have more that one filename.. but if you only have one, since the collect() returns a collection, you need to access the item in the collection, for instance nameoffile.head

Comment: @PascalSoucy can you please give some example. I am new to this language it would be helpful if you proved some examples.

Comment: @animal see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The key problem is that a `map` on an `RDD` returns a pointer to a new `RDD`.**

Here in your case, your `filenme` is an `RDD`, and you did:

```
var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1).mkString("|"))
```

where a `map` transformation is done on the `RDD`, that makes your `nameoffile` also an `RDD`

**Solution:**

You have to apply actions on your `RDD` in order to get a non-RDD value:

```
var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1)(0)).take(1)(0)
```

here `nameoffile` is a `String` whose value is `File8.HL7`

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val text: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/File8.HL7").coalesce(1)

var obrInd = 0

val filenme: RDD[String] = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/cloudera/File8.HL7").map { case (filename, content) => filename}

var nameoffile = filenme.map(_.split("/").takeRight(1)).collect().head

println(nameoffile) 

val result: RDD[String] = text.mapPartitions{part =>
        part.map{r => 
        if(code == "OBR")
        r + "|OBR_"+ nameoffile
    }
}
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: I tried your code but i am getting `OBR_[Ljava.lang.String;@1e9b706f` instead of File8.HL7

Comment: @animal don't forget the call to `head` after `collect`.  `collect` returns an array